# SQLite transaction save Point Issue

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, cross-platform

i've a strange error in SQLite using a transaction, that i cannot figured out....
below there is my code:

```
_connection.RunInTransaction(() =>
                {
                    _connection.UpdateAll(objProposte);
                    foreach (Proposte objProposta in objProposte)
                    {
                        string propostaID = objProposta.PropostaID;
                        List<ProposteDetails> lstProdDet = _connection.Table<ProposteDetails>().Where(x => x.PropostaID == propostaID).ToList();

                        if (lstProdDet != null && lstProdDet.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            //AN UPDATE GIVE ME THE SAME ERROR
                            _connection.DeleteAll(lstProdDet);
                            _connection.InsertAll(lstProdDet);
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Seems that the _connection.UpdateAll(objProposte); works correctly, but when i try to do something else in the same transaction i got the following exception:

> System.ArgumentException: savePoint is not valid, and should be the
>   result of a call to SaveTransactionPoint. Parameter name: savePoint
>   at SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.DoSavePointExecute (System.String
>   savePoint, System.String cmd) [0x00063] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0    at
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.Release (System.String savepoint)
>   [0x00000] in <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0    at
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.RunInTransaction (System.Action action)
>   [0x0001d] in <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0    at
>   SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection.InsertAll (System.Collections.IEnumerable
>   objects, System.Boolean runInTransaction) [0x0001e] in
>   <8f2bb39aeff94a30a8628064be9c7efe>:0

Reading on the internet seems something related to a nested transaction, but is not my situation because is all done in the same transaction.

Thanks,
L-

*edit* 28-05-2018 12:16: That configuration works.... but should do the same things of the above :(

```
string my_transaction_point = null;
            try
            {
                my_transaction_point = _connection.SaveTransactionPoint();
                    _connection.UpdateAll(objProposte, runInTransaction: false);
                    foreach (Proposte objProposta in objProposte)
                    {
                        string propostaID = objProposta.PropostaID;
                        List<ProposteDetails> lstProdDet = _connection.Table<ProposteDetails>().Where(x => x.PropostaID == propostaID).ToList();
                        if (lstProdDet != null && lstProdDet.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            _connection.DeleteAll(lstProdDet);
                            _connection.InsertAll(lstProdDet, runInTransaction: false);
                        }
                    }
                _connection.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _connection.RollbackTo(my_transaction_point);
                throw new Exception("UpdateProposta, " + ex.Message, ex);
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.UpdateAll` runs within its own transaction by default, you can turn that off by overriding the second parameter which defaults to `true`:

```
_connection.RunInTransaction(() =>
{
    _connection.UpdateAll(objProposte, false);

    // perform the rest of your CRUD operations
    ~~~
    ~~~
});
```

Comment: Using "false" in all the updateall/insertall/deleteall into the trasaction i got the same error :(

Comment: *edit* in deleteall the meaning is different, but is not that the problem.

Comment: @Legion `.DeleteAll` takes a `TableMapping` as its only parameter... (or no parameters if you use the generic version of it). What SQLite package are you using?

Comment: oh sry, I'm using that NugetPackage -> https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL , is something that I receive from the previous developer, so is too late to change it.

Comment: @Legion The project was forked from `sqlite-net-pcl` and it is not longer being maintained (for about 2+ years) :-/ I use the original `sqlite-net-pcl` as it has had a number updates since then (personally I have not had any problems like the error you are showing in using it...) The source is really simple, you should look it via the link you provided to see exactly what the transaction/save points are doing in it.

Comment: If you mean that (https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/) there was some bug on android Nougat/Oreo that cannot be fixed easily.... Øystein Krog release a specific version fot that 2 OS, that's why we use the Krog version, i'll try to update it with the last beta version and see if someone got fixed.

Comment: Got-it! The version 1.5.166-beta of sqlite-net-pcl fix previous issues and seems that fix my RunInTransaction() issue too.

Comment: @Legion Great to hear it.